# Deleting own question when I "lost interest"

Tags: discussion, questions, deleting

I asked a question, it has no answers and I don't consider it useful anymore. I have a feeling that it would be a waste of time if someone tried hard to make a solution now. Should I better delete it to avoid this situation?

Question in question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159900/how-to-output-latex-code-verbatim-in-htlatex-mixing-htlatex-with-mathjax

Comment: Two factors to consider: (1) are there any answers (2) is there likely to be more general interest.

Comment: @JosephWright Well, (1) no, (2) my feeling is that no, given the low votes.

Comment: @JosephWright not related to this Q but some additional factors 3) Number of Views for Q 4)Days of Q survival without Upvotes

Comment: Thanks for deleting the question. :-)

Comment: @TheLastError Were you going to answer it? If yes, I can undelete it of course ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For an unanswered question with few upvotes, I think that self-deletion is absolutely fine. That might be different it there were answers, even if not upvoted, or if the question had a lot of upvotes. So there will always be an element of judgement.

Comment: Thanks. I took the element of judgement and deleted it.

Comment: If you think it's an intelligent question after all, then what's the harm in letting it remain?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora, if the author has lost interest in the question, it is unlikely that they will ever accept an answer. Or address requests for clarification.

Comment: I had a question about the nomencl package [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158950/cant-get-nomenclature-to-work) that has a few replies and an "answer" from a newbie that's actually a question.  My original issue has since been resolved.  It was an issue with my OS rather than TeX.  Another SE.Tex user has recommended that I delete the question, as it's unlikely to be of much further help to anyone.  Is it possible for me to delete it, or would this have to be done to a moderator?  Also, will deleting a question have any impact on my reputation score?